# How do we call a jsp page from VB page?

Tags: vb.net, jsp, web-scraping

I have created a JSP page, which will accept parameter. Once the page received the parameter, it will return an XML to user.

I want to create a VB program, that will display a form and ask user to enter the value of the parameter, and then will pass it to the JSP page, and get the return XML and display it to user in VB program.

Is it possible to do so?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HttpRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) to [request a web page](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/mahesh/DownloadWebPage04252005073432AM/DownloadWebPage.aspx). Then just manipulate the URL to add [query string parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). If you need to do this via a POST request (versus GET), write the parameters in the body.